# How to describe what UX Developer does?

Tags: ux-field, confirmation, ux-designer

UX is often related to designing so it is more acceptable when people mention UX Designer to deliver wireframes, prototypes user research and more. What about UX Developer? How does both of it differs from each other? Does the employer expect him/her to develop project-worth front-end, whats the difference with a UI/Front-End Dev then? Enlighten me, it's confusing

Comment: have to say I've never heard the term UX Developer.... sounds like logically it should mean somebody who works on improving existing projects rather than working on something new.... though of course its probably just a term invented by someone who doesn't understand UX to mean they want a fabled full stack master wizard who will do the work of 10 for the price of 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

The UX title is the mostly abused nowadays, with any web developer or designer that can draft up a wireframe in Balsamiq/Axure/UXPin etc. labeling themselves UX experts...

So one would assume a UX Designer is former Graphic Designers that can make wireframes and pretty mockups.

A UX Developer is most likely someone with more HTML/CSS and possible other back-end languages that could produce functional prototypes.

In the chain of development hierarchy a Developer should have more experince than a Designer role... That's why I label myself as a UX Architect :)

Related Article:
https://uxmag.com/articles/hi-im-a-ux-developer-youre-a-what

Comment: why SHOULD a developer have more experience than a designer? They are two different fields that require its own separate level of proficiency.

Comment: @StanleyVM In my experience I've never met a "UX Developer" that didn't know design as well... But I've met many "UX Designers" that DO NOT know how to code...

Answer (score 0):

compared to technical skills I see ux as a way of thinking these days. You are putting priority on the user when building/rebuilding your product or testing it, regardless of what stage your product is at.

if you read bfritz artical. https://uxmag.com/articles/hi-im-a-ux-developer-youre-a-what

"The UX developer role is a discipline under the overall user experience umbrella. This means that to become a UX developer you need to have at least a general understanding of the core UX principles, philosophies, and methodologies. This includes, but is not limited to, the how and why of user research, wireframing, and the use of personas."

so in my opinion, in the product team from the product manager, designer to the developer, ux can and should be important.

Comment: @bfritz & ameen I actually posted this question after reading the said article...

Answer (score 0):

As known to most people, there is a child-parent relationship between UI and UX where UX is parent having UI as a child.

UX is more about experience in user driven experience and have a dramatically higher focus on development of wireframes and mockups. UX developer need to have knowledge of HTML/CSS and other technology as so make a easier and friendly user experience for customer at other end.

On contrary, UI is mixture of colours and appearance of an application/system. As emerged out of UX, this field have task of making the application/system attractive to user with simplest or out of box or inside box themes. This plays a role of making application/system stand out in the queue of its category.

On comparison, UX defines flow of app with layout of all components in that app where else UI is making the first impression on term of look and theme of app.

Both play a vital role in designing and employer do expect him/her to develop project with worth look(UI) n feel(UX). This is the demand of current industry where one need to know more than one thing.

Comment: IMO ,developing a production-ready project is not what UX Dev should be doing . Thank you for your answer but its more on UI vs UX. Perhaps you can elaborate more?